# TableView, setting editable cells

Tags: tableview, javafx-8

I try to make Table cells editable. I managed to do this with two Collumns that have String values in it, but I cant make this with columns that represent Integer values.

Places with X is where compiler get the error:

```
The method setCellFactory(Callback<TableColumn<DataModel,Integer>,TableCell<DataModel,Integer>>) in the type TableColumn<DataModel,Integer> is not applicable for the arguments  (Callback<TableColumn<DataModel,String>,TableCell<DataModel,String>>)
```

and places with XX is where compiler get the error:

```
The method setOnEditCommit(EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<DataModel,Integer>>) in the type TableColumn<DataModel,Integer> is not applicable for the arguments ((CellEditEvent<DataModel, Integer> event) -> {})
```

Heres the code:

```
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    //Tworzymy sobie kolumny, które będą odpowiadać oraz przyjmować konretne dane
    TableColumn<DataModel, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn<DataModel, String>("Name");
    nameColumn.setMinWidth(100);
    TableColumn<DataModel, String> surnameColumn = new TableColumn<DataModel, String>("Surname");
    surnameColumn.setMinWidth(100);
    TableColumn<DataModel, Integer> ageColumn = new TableColumn<DataModel, Integer>("Age");
    ageColumn.setMinWidth(100);
    TableColumn<DataModel, Integer> telNumberColumn = new TableColumn<DataModel, Integer>("Tel. Number");
    telNumberColumn.setMinWidth(100);

    //dodajemy kolumny do okna
    tableView.getColumns().addAll(nameColumn,surnameColumn,ageColumn,telNumberColumn);

    //podajemy nazwy zmiennych, których wartości mają się wyświetlać w poszczególnych kolumnach
    nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("sName"));
    surnameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("sSurname"));
    ageColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("iAge"));
    telNumberColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("iPhoneNumber"));

    //Sprawiamy że poszczególne kolumny stają się edytowalne
    nameColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<DataModel>forTableColumn());
    nameColumn.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<DataModel, String> event) -> {
        ((DataModel) event.getTableView().getItems(). get(event.getTablePosition().getRow())).  setsName(event.getNewValue());
    });
    surnameColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<DataModel>forTableColumn());
    surnameColumn.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<DataModel, String> event) -> {
        ((DataModel) event.getTableView().getItems(). get(event.getTablePosition().getRow())).  setsSurname(event.getNewValue());
    });
X   ageColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<DataModel>forTableColumn());
XX  ageColumn.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<DataModel, Integer> event) -> {
    //    ((DataModel) event.getTableView().getItems(). get(event.getTablePosition().getRow())).  setiAge(Integer.valueOf(event.getNewValue()));

    });
X   telNumberColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<DataModel>forTableColumn());
XX  telNumberColumn.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<DataModel, Integer> event) -> {
 //         ((DataModel) event.getTableView().getItems(). get(event.getTablePosition().getRow())).  setiPhoneNumber(Integer.valueOf(event.getNewValue()));

    });

    tableView.setPlaceholder(new Label("Pust tabelka!"));//jaki element dodać jeśli tabelka nie jest wyświetlona
    tableView.setEditable(true);

    tableView.setItems(dataList); //wczytujemy dane do przygotowanej tabelki

    buttAdd.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
        buttAddAction(e);
    });
}
```

Im taking oracle TableView tutorial, and its quite difficult. Help.

Comment: And what is the error? Stacktrace?

Comment: See the explanation at begining. Its a compiler error. I cant run the program.

Comment: Oops I did not see that line at first glance, my bad..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that `TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn()` is typed to a String value. See the default implementation:

```
public static <S> Callback<TableColumn<S,String>, TableCell<S,String>> forTableColumn() {
    return forTableColumn(new DefaultStringConverter());
}
```

What you need is the `TextFieldTableCell` with an [`IntegerStringConverter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/converter/IntegerStringConverter.html), for example:

```
ageColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<DataModel, Integer>forTableColumn(new IntegerStringConverter()));
```

Comment: I tryed to make custom cell edit events as showed in Oracle tutorial, and it works when its String property and doesnt work for SimpleIntegerValues. Again some problem with types. So, Isn't it best to keep every variable in Data Class(for example my DataModel) SimpleStringProperty to avoid conversions like that?

Comment: If you have additional questions, please ask them as new topics here on SO, the comments section is not the right place for that ;-)

Comment: @eckig - You saved my life :)

Answer (score 4):

I searched through a lot of answers and I've borrowed/extended/merged to this solution.  Edits are committed when focus moves from edited cell.  I have a public class for each datatype that can be represented in a table: EditingTextCell, EditingIntegerCell etc.  These public classes can be applied to any table provided that the data is represented as an observable list of a class that accesses the data to be displayed as properties.  I publish this solution because I was faced with creating a class for each column of each table in my application.  Currently, the double value and combobox cell versions are tied to specific columns of specific tables.  I'll do a generalized version of these as time permits.  Please forgive my not presenting the source links -- I forgot to bookmark them as I perused them.

Java documentation suggests that easier ways of doing this are forthcoming.

**Example usage for Integer field:**

```
    TableColumn<Factor, Number> noLevelsCol =
            new TableColumn<>("No. Levels");
    noLevelsCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory("numberLevels"));
    noLevelsCol.setMinWidth(40);
    noLevelsCol.setCellFactory(col -> new EditingIntegerCell<>());
    noLevelsCol.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<Factor, Number> t) -> {
        ((Factor) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                ).setNumberLevels(t.getNewValue().intValue());
    });
```

**Example usage for String field:**

```
    TableColumn<Factor, String> nameCol = new TableColumn<>("Name");
    nameCol.setMinWidth(60);
    nameCol.setCellValueFactory(
          new PropertyValueFactory("factorName"));
    nameCol.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
    nameCol.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<Factor, String> t) -> {
        ((Factor) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                ).setFactorName(t.getNewValue());
    });
```

**Definition of Factor class:**
public class Factor {

```
private final IntegerProperty factorID = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
public IntegerProperty getFactorID() {     return factorID;    }

private StringProperty factorName = new SimpleStringProperty();
public void setFactorName(String value) {
           factorNameProperty().set(value); }
public String getFactorName() { return factorNameProperty().get(); }
public StringProperty factorNameProperty() { 
    if (factorName == null) factorName = 
        new SimpleStringProperty(this, "factorName");
    return factorName; 
}

private IntegerProperty numberLevels = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
public void setNumberLevels(int value) {
         numberLevelsProperty().set(value); }
public IntegerProperty getNumberLevels() { return numberLevels;    }
public IntegerProperty numberLevelsProperty() { 
    if (numberLevels == null) numberLevels =
          new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "numberLevels");
    return numberLevels; 
}

private StringProperty listOfLevels = new SimpleStringProperty();
public void setListOfLevels(String value) {
         listOfLevelsProperty().set(value); }
public String getListOfLevels() { return listOfLevelsProperty().get(); }
public StringProperty listOfLevelsProperty() { 
    if (listOfLevels == null) listOfLevels = 
          new SimpleStringProperty(this, "listOfLevels");
    return listOfLevels; 
}


// Constructors
public Factor(int factorID, String factorName) {
    this.factorID.set(factorID);
    this.factorName.set(factorName);
    this.numberLevels.set(1);
    this.listOfLevels.set("-1, 1");
}

public Factor(int factorID, String factorName, int numberLevels,
                String listOfLevels) {
    this.factorID.set(factorID);
    this.factorName.set(factorName);
    this.numberLevels.set(numberLevels);
    this.listOfLevels.set(listOfLevels);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Factor{" + "factorName=" + factorName + '}';
}

public String[] getLevels() {
    return listOfLevels.getValue().split(",");
}
```

}

**Loading the data into the table**
    final ObservableList factorList =
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Factor(1, "Factor1", 2, "-1, 1")
    );

```
    factorTableView.setEditable(true);
    factorTableView.getColumns().clear();
    factorTableView.setItems(factorList);
    boolean addAll;
    addAll = factorTableView.getColumns().addAll(idCol,
                   nameCol, noLevelsCol, levelsCol);
```

**The EditingIntegerCell class**
public class EditingIntegerCell  extends TableCell {

```
    private TextField textField;
    private final Pattern intPattern = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");

    public EditingIntegerCell() {
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            super.startEdit();
            createTextField();
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(textField);
            textField.selectAll();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();

        setText((String) getItem().toString());
        setGraphic(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(Number item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if (isEditing()) {
                if (textField != null) {
                    textField.setText(getString());
                }
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
            } else {
                setText(getString());
                setGraphic(null);
            }
        }
    }

    private void createTextField() {
        textField = new TextField(getString());
        textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap()* 2);
        textField.focusedProperty().addListener(
            (ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean arg1, Boolean arg2) 
                        -> {
            if (!arg2) {
                processEdit();
            }
        });
    }

    private void processEdit() {
        String text = textField.getText();
        if (intPattern.matcher(text).matches()) {
            commitEdit(Integer.parseInt(text));
        } else {
            cancelEdit();
        }
    }

    private String getString() {
        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
    }
}
```

** The EditingTextCell class **
public class EditingTextCell extends TableCell {

```
    private TextField textField;

    public EditingTextCell() {
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            super.startEdit();
            createTextField();
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(textField);
            textField.selectAll();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();

        setText((String) getItem());
        setGraphic(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if (isEditing()) {
                if (textField != null) {
                    textField.setText(getString());
                }
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
            } else {
                setText(getString());
                setGraphic(null);
            }
        }
    }

    private void createTextField() {
        textField = new TextField(getString());
        textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap()* 2);
        textField.focusedProperty().addListener(
            (ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean arg1, Boolean arg2) 
                        -> {
            if (!arg2) {
                commitEdit(textField.getText());
            }
        });
    }

    private String getString() {
        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem();
    }
}
```