# Why simple “capture of ?” does not compile even type-safety could be compile-time inferred?

Tags: java, generics, type-inference, type-safety, unbounded-wildcard

I have a class with strict, simple generic type:

```
public class GenericTools<T> {

    private final Supplier<T> supplier;
    private final Consumer<T> consumer;

    public GenericTools(Supplier<T> supplier, Consumer<T> consumer) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
        this.consumer = consumer;
    }

    public Supplier<T> getSupplier() {
        return supplier;
    }

    public Consumer<T> getConsumer() {
        return consumer;
    }
}
```

**What is the exact reason for the fact that "capture of ?" cannot be used here and file does not compile?**

```
GenericTools<?> tools = new GenericTools<>(Math::random, System.out::println);
tools.getConsumer().accept(tools.getSupplier().get());
```

> Error:(27, 59) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be
>   converted to capture#1 of ?

With explicit `<Double>` it compiles with no problems:

```
GenericTools<Double> tools = new GenericTools<>(Math::random, System.out::println);
tools.getConsumer().accept(tools.getSupplier().get());
```

I have used **Java 1.8** to compile.

**Please note that this is completely not a duplicate of [Java generics “capture of ?”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40217285/java-generics-capture-of)**, where poster have no idea what we need to pass as "?"-typed argument when code requires it. In my case I am quite aware of capture mechanism, but stil type looking like supposed to work cannot be used. Most importantly, here I am asking about **the exact reason** (specification reference or something), not about **what I should pass**.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Unfortunatelly with "not for begginers" questions it's common to get even a full stack of "duplicate" votes just because someone's knowledge does not allow to see/understand subtle, but game-changing details. Even if it would be duplicate then in my opinion the original question should be closed and the new "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example", simplified and better quality should say as the main question in area to make Stackoverflow a better place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the type `?` is invariant, and `Object` is not a subtype of all types within the bounds of `?`.

I believe the Java 8 type inference is capable of inferring that `T` is `Double` on the RHS, but since you explicitly assign to a `GenericTools<?>` on the LHS, the capture is of an unbounded type variable, which unifies with the unbounded variable `T` which also has no bounds.

Without any bounds, the `T` in the signatures of `Supplier::get` and `Consumer::accept` are not guaranteed to be the *same* type -- remember, the type variable is invariant, as no co- or contra-variant bound is expressed. The erasure of the `T` on the `Supplier` side is just `Object`, and the compiler cannot insert a runtime check that the runtime type is actually `?` (because `?` is not reifiable!). Therefore: the type `Object` cannot be implicitly converted to `?` and compilation fails.

Answer (score 1):

As written in the [Generics tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html):

> ```
> Collection<?> c = new ArrayList<String>();
> c.add(new Object()); // Compile time error
> ```
>
> Since we don't know what the element type of `c` stands for, we cannot
>   add objects to it. The `add()` method takes arguments of type `E`, the
>   element type of the collection. When the actual type parameter is `?`,
>   it stands for some unknown type. Any parameter we pass to add would
>   have to be a subtype of this unknown type. Since we don't know what
>   type that is, we cannot pass anything in. The sole exception is `null`,
>   which is a member of every type.
>
> On the other hand, given a `List<?>`, we can call `get()` and make use of
>   the result. The result type is an unknown type, but we always know
>   that it is an object. It is therefore safe to assign the result of
>   `get()` to a variable of type `Object` or pass it as a parameter where the
>   type `Object` is expected.

This is equivalent to

```
GenericTools<?> tools = ...
tools.getConsumer().accept(new Object()); //or tools.getSupplier().get() which returns Object
```

Once you declare your generic type this is what the compiler will know for the rest of the calls. `getConsumer().accept()` will have to accept `?` (but it can't) and `getSupplier().get()` will have to return `Object`.

When declaring `GenericTools<Double>` you retain type information and both `getConsumer().accept()` and `getSupplier().get()` know that they are working with `Double`.