# Generics - "capture<?>" can not be applied to "?"

Tags: java, generics

What does "`caputure<?>`" mean in generics error messges? Consider following example:

```
interface Model<T> { T get(); }

static class DefaultModel<T> implements Model<T> {
    final T t;
    public DefaultModel(T t) { this.t = t; }
    @Override public T get() { return t; }
}

interface CellPopulator<T> {}

interface Column<T,S> extends CellPopulator<T> {}

static class Row {}

public static class Table<T,S> {
    public void updateCellItem(Model<Column<T,S>> model) {}
}
```

Types usage with unresolved conflict:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Model<CellPopulator<Row>> gridCellModel = null;

    Table<Row,?> table = new Table<>();
    Column<Row,?> tableCell = (Column<Row, ?>) gridCellModel.get();
    Model<Column<Row,?>> tableCellModel = new DefaultModel<>(tableCell);

    // Model<Column<Row,capture<?>>> can not be applied to Model<Column<Row,?>>
    table.updateCellItem(tableCellModel); // COMPILATION ERROR
}
```

Comment: This, [Java generics “capture of ?”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40217285/java-generics-capture-of), may be a better duplicate

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter Thanks, I will check it.

Comment: Also please check [my search strategy](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+generics+capture+cannot+be+applied+to+site:stackoverflow.com)